# vb.net send string to a different program and get the result

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've been developing a .net application for the company I work for, there is just one part I can't seem to do. I need to send a string to a textbox of another program and then copy the result. The result is shown in a label. Currently we hand type the string and manually copy the label text, so I know the information can be copied I just don't know how to do it via code.

The application I need to send the text too is also written with the .net framework if that helps.

Any answers are appreciated :)

Cheers.

Comment: doesn't help much - put more light on what you want to do. Another program in form of what? forms, webservice or what?

Comment: Hi, it's a form. Please follow the link to see a screen shot.
http://imgur.com/yum6L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use native *SendMessage*() from user32.dll. If you dont know how to import a dll command,
see [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from MSDN.
 Once you know how to import a dll command, use *FindWindow*() to find the window handle of your application and send the string using *SendMessage*().

The other alternatives is to use socket. Send the message via local network (localhost).
Here's a [small tutorial](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/192.html) about Socket. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This seems like a very simple way to go about it, thanks! I'll give it a go.

Comment: Aditya APP, your link is broken. T_T